# format date string in access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a where clause in an old dusty vb.net application

```
Dim dsAutoFoods As New DataSet
Dim tblAutoFoods As DataTable
Dim adAutoFoods As New OleDbDataAdapter("[qryFilter AutoFoods for Disagged Primary Foods]", connection )
adAutoFoods.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
adAutoFoods.Fill(dsAutoFoods, "AutoFoods")
tblAutoFoods = dsAutoFoods.Tables(0)

sb = "INTAKEDATE = Format('18/09/2011 12:00:00 AM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN:SS AM/PM')"

Dim rootFood As DataRow() = tblAutoFoods.Select(sb)
```

And I don't know how to format the where clause to use the date string '18/09/2011 12:00:00 AM' properly.

How do I format strings to dates?

I used :

```
Dim dateValue As Date
Date.TryParseExact(rdrKeySet("IntakeDate").ToString(), _
   "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", _
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
   Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue)
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ParseExact or TryParseExact method of Date to parse string to date,

```
Dim value As Date
Date.TryParseExact("17/10/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
           Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, value)

sb = "INTAKEDATE=#" value & "#"

'or 

sb = "INTAKEDATE='" value & "'"
```